# Matlab y-axis invisible but reappears when exporting

Tags: matlab

I am plotting in Matlab 2014b and I want the y-axis to be invisible. This is what I have done to achieve this:

```
ax = gca; 
ax.YTick = [];
ax.YColor = [1 1 1];
```

This works fine but when I export the figure to a `.tif` file, the y-axis is no longer white.

```
print -r600 -dtiff myfig.tif
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method to make an individual axis visible or invisible. The only option is to hide the axis, as you have attempted.

The complete axes properties documentation can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html

I tested out the below method to make the x-axis invisible, as described here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76743-how-to-make-only-x-axis-invisible-y-axis-stays-visible

```
handleAxes = gca;
plot ( handleAxes , rand ( 10 , 1 ) );
axesPos = get ( handleAxes , 'position' );
handleAxesNew = axes ( 'position' , axesPos );
linkaxes ( [ handleAxes handleAxesNew ] , 'y' );
axesPos(3) = eps;
set ( handleAxesNew , 'position' , axesPos , 'xtick' , [] , 'xticklable' , [] );
set ( handleAxes , 'visible', 'off' );
print -r600 -dtiff 'test.tif'
```

The resulting tif file appears like:

[image]